# How to use RichTextBox similar to Richtx32.ocx for Office 365 64 bit

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, richtextbox, ocx

I want to use RichTextBox ocx control for Office 365 64 bit. But the control supports only 32 bit and doesn't work for Office 64 bit.

Is there any solution to use this control for Office 365 64 bit or any other solution would be much helpful and appreciated.

Comment: @braX: Isn't that about 32/64-bit Windows OS, not 32/64-bit Microsoft 365?

Comment: What is your end goal? What exactly do you need to implement?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev
My use case is to create a VBA macro using RichTextBox (richtx32.ocx) control that allows users to enter and edit formatted text, including the ability to apply different fonts, styles, and colors to text. The macro will be used in the Office 365 64 bit version applications. So, I want to create a macro for 64 bit applications but the Rich Text Box is supported only for 32 bit Office 365 applications.

Comment: @Gustav It is about Office 365 64-bit.

Comment: @Kumar: Exactly. The comment from braX (now deleted) was about 32/64-bit Windows.